# How to read the value of an XML tag having attributes using minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have an XML which looks like this.

```
<nb:myelement param='oxygen'>Value</nb:element>
```

I am using the following python code.

```
for sub in dom.getElementsByTagName('nb:myelement'):
   if(sub.getAttributeNode("param").nodeValue == 'oxygen'):
      value = sub.getElementsByTagName('nb:myelement')[0].toxml()
```

But the last line is throwing an `index out of range execption`. How do I get the 'value' enclosed by a tag that also has attributes?

Comment: Is there are reason that you can't use `xml.etree.ElementTree` or the excellent lxml library?  It pains me to see people still using DOM when Python has such excellent alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other **nb:myelement** elements in your **nb:myelement**. So last line is really

```
[][0].toxml()
```

If there is only text in **nb:myelement**, just use text node of this element

```
sub.firstChild.nodeValue
```